# unmet dependencies, linux-server depends: linux-headers-server, but boot is full

Tags: server, apt, package-management, dependencies

Hello I have an problem with unmet dependencies, but I cant fix it.

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.45.54) but 3.2.0.49.59 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I tried:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
........
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.2.0-49-generic_3.2.0-49.75_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed in write on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-generic': No space left on device
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

I tried as well:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

But doesn't work cause no space left.
So I tried to remove some linux-images, but:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-3.2.0-37 linux-headers-3.2.0-37-generic linux-image-3.2.0-37-generic 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-server : Depends: linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.45.54) but 3.2.0.49.59 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

Can anyone help me?

//Update:
Removed old linux-header-* and linux-images-* with dpkg, but:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-server
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-server
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,734 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
 linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.45.54); however:
  Version of linux-image-server on system is 3.2.0.49.59.
 linux-server depends on linux-headers-server (= 3.2.0.45.54); however:
  Version of linux-headers-server on system is 3.2.0.49.59.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

//Update 2:
Fixed it by removing linux-server, linux-headers-server and linux-image-server.

Comment: Update 2 solved my problem using: sudo apt-get remove -f linux-server linux-headers-server linux-image-server

Comment: is that Really?

Answer (score 2):

One solution that I have found to work quite well is this:

Remove the offending packages:

```
sudo apt-get remove -f linux-server linux-headers-server linux-image-server
```

Then re-install them:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-server linux-headers-server linux-image-server
```

Comment: works like charm. I took backup of old images etc and ran `sudo apt-get install -f` many time but it failed again and again.